# Showing FAB in particular fragment

Tags: android

I want to show FAB in only 1 place - RecyclerviewFragment and to hide() it when navigating to other fragments, then show() whenever back on RecyclerviewFragment. Hiding it when navigating to AddFragment for example is working, but the other way around is not. The FAB is located in activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

add the following dependency to your gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

**and remove fab from activity_main.xml**

and add this to your fragment which recyclerview is

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_alarm_black_24dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

and call on Fab click listener in fragment

done :)

Comment: I'm actually going to add the scrolling FAB behavior, so it won't work for me, as the whole layout will behave this way.